# How to write query showing the patient's name, their prescription, dosage, and the prescribing provier

Tags: mysql

I am very new to MySQL and still am having trouble with creating queries

[image]

Comment: You should learn from SQL basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this in sections so that you can see how to build a query and, hopefully, begin to understand enough of the basics to begin experimenting with queries to provide samples when you face challenges in the future.

First, you want a patient's name, the name of their medicine, how much of that medicine they need, and the name of the insurance company for the patient.

Okay, so you'll need something like this to get the necessary fields:

```
SELECT `User_Account`.`Last_Name`,
       `User_Account`.`First_Name`,
       `Product`.`Name`,
       `Prescription`.`dosage`,
       `Accepted_Insurance`.`Company_Name`
```

Now, because there are several tables where this data is coming from, you need to find a way to join them. We can do that with the diagram you shared as well as `FROM`, `INNER JOIN`, and `ON`:

```
  FROM `User_Account` INNER JOIN `Customer` ON `User_Account`.`id` = `Customer`.`user_id`
```

This is a very basic way to join two tables together. Of course, your query will require several more tables in order to return everything in a single trip to the database. So, to include more tables, we add more `JOIN`s:

```
  FROM `User_Account` INNER JOIN `Customer` ON `User_Account`.`id` = `Customer`.`user_id`
                      INNER JOIN `Prescription` ON `Customer`.`idCustomer` = `Prescription`.`customer`
                      INNER JOIN `Pharmaceutical` ON `Prescription`.`pharmaceutical_id` = `Pharmaceutical`.`idPharmaceutical`
                      INNER JOIN `Product` ON `Pharmaceutical`.`product_id` = `Product`.`idProduct`
                      INNER JOIN `Provider_Policy` ON `Customer`.`provider_policy_id` = `Provider_Policy`.`idPolicy`
                      INNER JOIN `Accepted_Insurance` ON `Provider_Policy`.`policy_provider_id` = `Accepted_Insurance`.`idInsurance`
```

Of course, you will probably want to return just one record for a given prescription, or a series of records if you're making a report for a patient or their insurance agency, so we can use `WHERE` to filter the records.

For this example, let's grab just one specific prescription:

```
 WHERE `Prescription`.`idPrescription` = 12345
```

There is a lot more you can do to make your query easier to read, simpler to write, and more verbose, but this should give you the basics needed to answer the initial question, plus enough to encourage you to experiment. Because this is just a `SELECT` statement, there is no risk of changing or deleting data. Hopefully, once you see the data come back from your database, you'll start asking a lot of "What if" questions.

- What if I filter by company?
- What if I include an "expiration date" so prescriptions older than X cannot be filled?
- What if I want to include the patient's address?
- What if I want to show all prescriptions for a specific drug?
- etc.

Comment: Is greater verbosity an ambition?